# Is there a way to create a module that can read the directory that it is used in? (TypeScript/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

What I'm trying do is make a handler that will read a folder that it is in. However, this handler is a module that will be imported into multiple folders.

For example, if given the current directory:

```
->Main
   ->folder a
      ->languages
   a.js
   ->folder b
      ->languages
   b.js
   ->folder c
      ->languages
   c.js
d.js
```

**d.js - handler used in a.js, b.js and c.js**

```
var Translate = ((lang) => {
  // this line below is what I want to know how to do. 
  import { lang } from "./languages/"+lang;

  // do stuff with lang
}

export { Translate }
```

With the d.js handler, it should be able to be used in a.js/b.js/c.js. However I want to know how to read the directory (in this case the language folder) it is being imported in rather than from the handler.  I'm doing this to handle multiple languages for an app, and I figure this way its a lot easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing the code in NodeJS environment, you can use this to get the current directory name:

```
import path from "path";
const dirName = path.basename(path.dirname(filename));
```

The dirName variable will contain the folder name as a string.
Then you can dynamically import using ES6 template literal.

```
import { lang } from `./languages/${dirname}`
```